# Как в параметр sql запроса вставить поле списка обьектов C#

Tags: c#, sql, list

Код:

```
    class Group
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

}
```

class GetData
    {
        public string[] lines2;

```
    public List<Group> GetDataGroups()
    {
        List<Group> Groups = new List<Group>();
        lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User2\Desktop\c#\Groups.txt");
        for (int index = 1; index < lines2.Length; index++)
        {
            string[] items = lines2[index].Split(new char[] { '|' });

            Groups.Add(new Group() { Id = Int32.Parse(items[0]) });
            Groups.Add(new Group() { Number = items[1] });
        }
        return Groups;
    }

    public void InsertDataGroups()
    {


        string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO dbo.Groups(id,Number) VALUES(@id,@Number)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, this.con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlDbType.Text);
            cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value=??
            cmd.Parameters["@number"].Value=??
```

Как обратится к списку в который я записал все данные с файла?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае, вероятно, проще будет сделать серию вызовов INSERT, вставляя элементы по одному -- так проще всего.

Вообще же, передача в SQL-код списка объектов -- это проблема, простых путей нет. Есть несколько альтернатив. Вы не указали какая у вас СУБД, поэтому предполагаю что MS SQL Server.

1. **Сериализовать список объектов в XML**, соответственно, в SQL-коде разобрать XML средствами T-SQL. Способ также хорошо подходит чтобы передать в SQL сразу несколько списков. Удобно тем что в C# есть средства для сериализации, в T-SQL есть средства для разбора XML. Недостаток -- громоздкий код разбора в SQL.
2. **Table-Valued Parameters** -- табличные параметры.
   Недостаток -- до передачи параметра нужно объявить тип параметра через `CREATE TYPE`. Делать это нужно один раз на базу, т.е. такой тип параметра хранится в базе и используется, например, при вызове хранимых процедур.
3. **Передать строку** типа VARCHAR(MAX) или NVARCHAR(MAX), в которой через разделители перечислены объекты и их поля. Формат -- любой, лишь бы его было удобно разбирать в SQL. Например, можно использовать Comma-Separated Values (CSV).
   Недостаток -- неудобно разбирать на стороне SQL, громоздкий код разбора.
4. **Использование временной таблицы**.
   Создаётся таблица со знаком # в начале имени, в неё делаются INSERT, затем выполняется код который делает с этими записями что-то полезное. Затем удаляется временная таблица.

Подробнее можно найти тут:
http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html